# Display different Date Format

Tags: android, datetime, calendar, android-calendar

my date format is display like this :

Date : 19/01/2015(January)

Here is the code :

```
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
String day = cal.getDisplayName(dayOfWeek, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
```

But I want to display in like this :

Date : 19/01/2015(Mon)

How can i modify the codes? Please help me take a look.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it standard Java way

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy(EEE)")
dateFormat.format(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below three lines:

```
String format = "dd-MM-yyyy(EEE)";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
```

Logs -  01-21 16:39:34.125: I/System.out(11052):                dd-MM-yyyy(EEE) 01-01-1970(Thu)